# как работает конструкция (pizza_type: PizzaType) -> Pizza в функции def create_pizza(pizza_type: PizzaType) -> Pizza:?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
from enum import Enum  

class PizzaType(Enum):    
    """  
    Перечисление текущих рецептов пицц в пиццерии,    
    которые можно приготовить    
    """    
    MARGARITA = 0,    
    MEXICO = 1,  
    STELLA = 2  

class Pizza:
    """
    Базовый класс для пицц, которые можно
    приготовить в пиццерии
    """
    def __init__(self, price: float):
        self.__price = price # цена пиццы

    def get_price(self) -> float:
        return self.__price


class PizzaMargarita(Pizza):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(3.5)


class PizzaMexico(Pizza):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(17.5)


class PizzaStella(Pizza):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(5.5)


def create_pizza(pizza_type: PizzaType) -> Pizza:
    """
    Factory Method
    """
    factory_dict = {
        PizzaType.MARGARITA: PizzaMargarita,
        PizzaType.MEXICO: PizzaMexico,
        PizzaType.STELLA: PizzaStella
    }
    return factory_dict[pizza_type]()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for pizza in PizzaType:
        my_pizza = create_pizza(pizza)
        print(f'Pizza type: {pizza}, price: {my_pizza.get_price()}')
```

Comment: Я не понимаю что какую роль выполняет двоеточие и ->

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#use-cases

Answer (score 1):

Это просто аннотации.

```
def create_pizza(pizza_type: PizzaType) -> Pizza:
```

Такая запись нам говорит, что:

- параметр `pizza_type` имеет тип `PizzaType`
- функция `create_pizza` возвращает результат типа `Pizza`

Такая вот попытка сделать из питона строго типизированный язык. Хотя аннотации только подсказывают типы объектов, проверяются они линтером или другими специальными средствами, сам язык питон, насколько я понимаю, аннотации игнорирует и может спокойно выполнять код при их нарушении.